# How to dynamically set title in Pie Chart of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to set a dynamically passed text as title based on if else condition in a pie chart using high-charts plugin. I tried events attribute, as well as `chart.setTitle({text:mydesiredtitle})`, but it didn't help me out.

I've surfed forums and blogs, nothing helped me. Here I'm attaching my code:

```
var textElement;
function RenderDonutChart(container,complete,incomplete,fillColor,nonfillColor) {
var dataText = true;
//complete and incomplete are integers
//container is my div to load chart.
if(!($.isNumeric(complete)))
{
    dataText = false;
    complete = 0;
    incomplete = 100;
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: container,
        type: 'pie',
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor: null,
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            animation: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            innerSize: '90%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    title: {

        text: '',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: 10,
      },

   events: {
        load: function () {
            alert("load works");
            if(!(dataText))
            {
                if(textElement != null)
                {
                    textElement.destroy();
                }
                alert("null dataText");
                textElement = '<span style="font-family:abel-Regular;font-size:16px;color:#ffffff">Not Applicable</span>';
                chart.setTitle({text: textElement});
             }
            else
            {
                if(textElement != null)
                {
                     textElement.destroy();
                }
                alert("true dataText");
                textElement = '<div style="font-family:abel-Regular;font-size:38px;color:#e57104">'
                        + complete +
                        '%</div><br><span style="font-family:abel-Regular;font-size:16px;color:#ffffff">Completed</span>';
                chart.setTitle({text: textElement});
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [complete,incomplete]
    }],
    colors: [fillColor, nonfillColor]
});
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? chart.setChartTitleText(mydesiredtitle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword refers to the object itself in the `load` event.  Use `this` instead of `chart` (which isn't set yet by the time the load event is fired) and you'll be fine.

```
   chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var textElement = '<span style="font-family:abel-Regular;font-size:16px;color:#000">Not Applicable</span>';
                 this.setTitle({text: textElement});
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hmcw9wu/1/

Comment: Thanks @Barbara Laird.I just noted that I've misplaced the load event from your answer and it resolved my issue.Also,Thanks for mentioning "this.setTitle({text: textElement});",it's also really helpful.